# atlassian jenkins: checkout revision of last successful build

Tags: svn, jenkins

is there a way in Jenkins to checkout the code of the last successful jenkins build?

For example:
Jenkins build job #3 and checks out SVN-Revision 21; runs all tests and validates its correctness.
Jenkins build job #4 and checks out SVN-Revision 22; runs all tests and finds some faults.

now i want to find the last successful build in jenkins (#3) and checkout the code from my SVN-Repository (Revision 21).

Is there a way to do so?

Thank you for your help...

Answer (score 1):

Use wget to grab the last successful build number and go from there, e.g.,

```
wget -qO- my_Jenkins_server/job/my_job/lastSuccessfulBuild/buildNumber
```

Comment: but how "to go frome there"? receiving the jenkins build number of the last successful build is not the problem. receiving the the svn revision nummber is.

Comment: If you know the last successful build number, and go to the changelog.xml of that build number, the latest commit should be listed in the first line of that file.